Incorrect documentation of cookies in "consent" banner
The information in the Cookie Consent popup does not satisfy your legal obligation of informed consent, because it is completely unreadable. That is not, however, the point of this bug report; only an explanation of why it's taken so long to report.
A section of the information (from serverfault.com) follows. (I had to omit some erroneous entries, because there was just too much wrong: hopefully this gives an overview.)
Strictly Necessary Cookies
First Party Cookies


Name__cf_bm
Hostserverfault.com
TypeFirst Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies
DescriptionThe __cf_bm cookie is a cookie necessary to support Cloudflare Bot Management, currently in private beta. As part of our bot management service, this cookie helps manage incoming traffic that matches criteria associated with bots. This is a CloudFoundry cookie



NameOptanonConsent
Hostmeta.serverfault.com
TypeFirst Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies
DescriptionThis cookie is set by the cookie compliance solution from OneTrust. It stores information about the categories of cookies the site uses and whether visitors have given or withdrawn consent for the use of each category. This enables site owners to prevent cookies in each category from being set in the users browser, when consent is not given. The cookie has a normal lifespan of one year, so that returning visitors to the site will have their preferences remembered. It contains no information that can identify the site visitor.



Nametheme
Hoststackoverflow.com
TypeFirst Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies
DescriptionSet when switching between desktop and mobile themes



Nameuauth
Hoststackoverflow.com
TypeFirst Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookied
DescriptionUsed to preform network-wide login.



Nameusr
Hostserverfault.com
TypeFirst Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies



imgur.com


Name__cfduid
Hostimgur.com
TypeThird Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies
DescriptionThis domain is owned by Imgur LLC. The company provides image sharing platform and online advertising services.



stackexchange.com
__cf_bm with the description "This is a CloudFoundry cookie", and also prov (listed as a First Party Cookie on serverfault.com earlier).
google.com
Name__Secure-3PAPISID
Hostgoogle.com
TypeThird Party
CategoryStrictly Necessary Cookies
DescriptionThis domain is owned by Google. The main business activity is: Authentication.
This is actually an ad-tracking cookie. cspservices.de's Cookie Policy describes it as:

Builds a profile of website visitor interests to show relevant and personalized ads through retargeting.

Ofcom's cookie policy describes it as:

Google cookie used to profile the interests of website visitors to serve relevant and personalised ads through retargeting.

Saying it's for "Authentication" is a lie. Treating this as a necessary cookie is a crime, but fortunately this looks like it's just a documentation problem.
Targeting Cookies
First Party Cookies


Namebito
Hostbidr.io
TypeFirst Party
CategoryTargeting Cookies
DescriptionThis domain appears to be registered privately in the US. The purpose of its cookies is unclear. In the absence of further information they are classified in the most intrusive category.




(I would be much obliged if someone edited this question into shape; I don't have time for a proper write-up.)

Either the cookie is classified and described incorrectly, or it's the wrong name– over on Meta's cookie notice, __Secure-3PAPISID is indeed listed as an advertising cookie, but the closely named __Secure-3PSID is an auth cookie... maybe the dialogue is listing the wrong one? Accessing Stack from the US, I don't get either of these cookies, so I can't even confirm what's really coming through.

@zcoop98 They're both targeting cookies, according to Ofcom. Maybe Ofcom's wrong? (But it gives specific, if vague, descriptions, so I'm inclined to believe them over Facebook.) I can't find much information from Google about this. (cspservices.de agrees with Ofcom, though uses a copy-pasted description so I trust it less.)

This 2023 blog post gives credence to the idea that __Secure-1PSID is some kind of authentication cookie. If Google's using the same cookies for authentication and ad-tracking, then Stack Exchange would not be allowed to use them (unless the user has explicitly consented to ad-tracking), and has to seek an alternative way to authenticate Google users. (It looks like they're currently not using them, so that's fine.)

I block every cookie with the exception of 1st party ones from the few network sites I use. As far as I know, I am blocking the imgur cookie. This is a "strictly needed cookie", yet I never experienced any issue with imgur images on the site. I think "strictly necessary" here needs some though.

@zcoop98 looks like it's only shown for EU.
